# Convert a byte[] to Image without using a MemoryStream

Tags: c#

I am having a problem exporting SQL images to files. I first initialize a List. MyRecord is a class with GraphicName, and Graphic properties. When I try to go through the list and save MyRecord.Graphic to disk I get a first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'. I realize this is because when I converted the bytes from the database to an Image I used a **using** statement with the MemoryStream. I can not use the using statement and it all works, but I am worried about memory usage / memory leaks on up to 6,000 records. Is there another way to convert the bytes to an image or is there a better design to do this?

```
... prior code
using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        MyRecord record = new MyRecord();
        record.GraphicId = reader["GRAPHIC_ID"].ToString();
        record.Graphic = !reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("IMAGE")) ? GetImage((byte[])reader["IMAGE"]) : null;
        records.Add(record);
    }
... more code

private Image GetImage(byte[] rawImage)
{
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(rawImage))
    {
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you save the `byte[]` directly to a file?

Comment: @Oded I could, but the image gets displayed so at some point I also need images. Yours is a possible solution in a redesign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *shouldn't* use a `using` statement with a stream that will be passed to `Image.FromStream`, as the `Image` class is basically responsible for the stream from then on. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx):

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.

Just change your code to:

```
private Image GetImage(byte[] rawImage)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream(rawImage);
    return Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

... but then make sure you dispose of your `Image` objects later. That will dispose of the stream, allowing the memory to be garbage collected. Then there shouldn't be any memory leaks - but you need to work out whether you can really load all 6000 images into memory at a time anyway.

(If you don't dispose of the `Image` objects, they're likely to be finalized anyway at some point - but it would be better to dispose of them deterministically.)

Comment: I knew I couldn't use the using statement, but I was hoping for an answer that allowed me to keep an image in the list. I changed the design to save the byte[] an added a GetAsImage method to the class. Then the caller is responsible for disposing of the image.